# Microchip's XC8 Linker doesn't recognize some custom section names

Tags: pic, microchip, xc8, linker

Slightly related to this one: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254734/microchip-xc8-how-to-pack-code-against-an-upper-limit

I can relocate code just fine, but I'm having some trouble with constants:

Example code:

```
#include <xc.h>

unsigned char buffer[16];

__section("SecConst1") const unsigned char constants1[] = "const1";
__section("SecConst2") const unsigned char constants2[] = "const2";
//__section("SecText1") const unsigned char constants1[] = "const1";
//__section("SecText2") const unsigned char constants2[] = "const2";

__section("SecText1") void fill_buffer1(void)
{
    unsigned char i = sizeof(constants1);
    do
    {
        i--;
        buffer[i] = constants1[i];
    }
    while(i);
}

__section("SecText2") void fill_buffer2(void)
{
    unsigned char i = sizeof(constants2);
    do
    {
        i--;
        buffer[i] = constants2[i];
    }
    while(i);
}

__section("SecText") void main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        fill_buffer1();
        fill_buffer2();
    }
}
```

Linker Options:

```
-L-aClass1=1200h-17FFh,1800h-1FFDh -L-dClass1=2 -L-pSecText1=Class1 -L-pSecText2=Class1 -L-pSecText=Class1
```

If I build it with no linker options, or if I only specify the functions (as above), it builds with no errors and I see all of the section names in the map file, so I know they're all there.  But if I specify where to place a constant, the build fails because that section name was not defined.  If I switch to the other set of constant declarations (swap the comments), then *those* names are suddenly not defined.

I feel that this is a bug in the toolchain, and I've told Microchip about it via their support site, but does anyone know of a good workaround?

I'd rather not specify the address of every constant directly in the source code because the complete project has a lot of them and they can all change size and contents from one version to the next.

I'm using a PIC16F1454, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't matter for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a ticket to Microchip's tech support, and after a few days, they found that

```
 #pragma psect <default_section>=<new_section>
```

would work for constants just like it's supposed to.  They've made a note of the problem and said they'd fix it in the next release so either that or __section("new_section") will also work for constants.

I don't like the #pragma because you have to know the default_section (can be found by compiling successfully without the directive and searching the map file) and because it affects the entire source file, while __section() only affects the one item that it's used with.  But for my application, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This stackoverflow question [Declare a specific address for a string in MPLAB XC8 Microchip complier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896180/declare-a-specific-address-for-a-string-in-mplab-xc8-microchip-complier) contains an answer:

Rather than tell the linker, for example `-L-pappnfo=0x78E0`

There is syntax to *directly* specify the location of a variable, for example:

```
const unsigned char _app_nfo[31] @ 0x78E0 = {"V0.0 No        - 05/12/12"};
```

However, this doesn't sound like what you want to do. You say:

> I'd rather not specify the address of every constant directly in the
>   source code because the complete project has a lot of them and they
>   can all change size and contents from one version to the next.

Section "3.4.3.3 HOW DO I PLACE VARIABLES IN PROGRAM MEMORY?" of the [MPLAB® XC8 C Compiler User’s Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52053B.pdf) says:

> The const qualifier implies that the qualified variable is read only.
>   As a consequence of this, any variables (except for auto variables or
>   function parameters) qualified const are placed in program memory,
>   thus freeing valuable data RAM

So it looks like all `const` variables are put in program space automatically, which I think is what you want.

Comment: So far, so good, but I want to put them between 1200h and 1FFDh in program space, not just anywhere in program space.  That's the part that doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I find PIC's heavy going, and the XC8 compiler manual is a bit weird. I am much more familiar with AVR, ARM, Freescale, ...